# Google cloud pubsub subscription not found on cloud but found on local

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

so I have weird problem, I have subscription in Google Cloud pub sub. In my local machine, the program can find the subscription without any problem, but in cloud (I use GCP VM) I get this error:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: com.google.api.gax.rpc.NotFoundException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=subs_id).
```

Eventhough I used subs_id in my local too.

My setup is like this:

1. Service account credentials.json:

> ```
> {
>   "type": "service_account",
>   "project_id": "project-id-123",
>   "private_key_id": "privateKeyId",
>   "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivateKey\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
>   "client_email": "user@project-id-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
>   "client_id": "clientId",
>   "auth_uri": "auth_uri",
>   "token_uri": "token_uri",
>   "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "certs_url",
>   "client_x509_cert_url": "clients_certs_url
> }
> ```

2. Code (mostly copied from their documentation):

> > @Component public class GoogleCloudPubSubListenerImpl implements
> >     GoogleCloudPubSubListener, InitializingBean {
> >
> > private static final String PROJECT_ID =
> >     ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();
> >
> > private static final Logger LOGGER =
> >     LoggerFactory.getLogger(GoogleCloudPubSubListenerImpl.class);
> >
> > @Value("${pub.sub.subscription}")
> >     private String subId;
> >
> > @Override   public void listenPubSub() {
> >         ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(PROJECT_ID, subId);
> >
> > ```
> > Subscriber subscriber;
> > try {
> >   subscriber = Subscriber
> >       .newBuilder(subscriptionName,
> >           new someService()).build();
> >   subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
> >
> > } catch (Exception e) {
> >   LOGGER.error("Subscriber err : {}, {}", e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
> > }   }
> > ```

In cloud I run this command:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull subs_id
ERROR: (gcloud.pubsub.subscriptions.pull) NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=subs_id).
```

But this command succeed:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull projects/project-id-123/subscriptions/subs_id
Listed 0 items.
```

When I change the subs_id in my program to `projects/project-id-123/subscriptions/subs_id`
I get error:

```
Invalid character "/" in path section "projects/project-id-123/subscriptions/subs_id".
```

Anyone having same problem? Need advice here ... Thank you

Comment: In your code, log the value of the variable you created called `PROJECT_ID`.  What is its value?

Comment: Oh in cloude it shows my VM project (the subscriber) rather than project-id-123 (the publisher) I think I try to hard code it to project-id-123

Comment: you can use the gcloud config set command to set the default project ... check this doc https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set